# Creating arrays in C based on data sheet

Tags: c, arrays, buffer, spi

I'm extremely new to the c language (obj-c, swift usually) and I'm working with some Cypress BLE boards. I'm trying to control a simple LED.

Per [the documentation](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2343/APA102C.pdf) I should simply be writing to a SPI bus to control the LED.

Here is the relevant part: 
[image]

So I write 32 bits of 0's to start. Then the RGB array. Then 32 bits of all 1's. Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
static uint8 startFrame[32] = {0,0,0,0};
static uint8 colorFrame[32] = {1, 255, 0, 0};
static uint8 endFrame[32] = {1,1,1,1};


SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(startFrame, 32);
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(colorFrame, 32);
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(endFrame,   32);
```

My thought is that an `int` is 8 bits so putting `{1,1,1,1}` should be of size 32. Again, I'm extremely new and hacking my way through this. Any help is very much appreciated!

Documentation for `SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray`:

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name: SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray
****************************************************************************//**
*
*  Places an array of data into the transmit buffer to be sent.
*  This function is blocking and waits until there is a space available to put
*  all the requested data in the transmit buffer. The array size can be greater
*  than transmit buffer size.
*
* \param wrBuf: pointer to an array of data to be placed in transmit buffer. 
*  The width of the data to be transmitted depends on TX data width selection 
*  (the data bit counting starts from LSB for each array element).
* \param count: number of data elements to be placed in the transmit buffer.
*
* \globalvars
*  SPI_1_txBufferHead - the start index to put data into the 
*  software transmit buffer.
*  SPI_1_txBufferTail - start index to get data from the software
*  transmit buffer.
*
*******************************************************************************/
void SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(const uint8 wrBuf[], uint32 count)
{
    uint32 i;

    for (i=0u; i < count; i++)
    {
        SPI_1_SpiUartWriteTxData((uint32) wrBuf[i]);
    }
}
```

Which I've also tried this:

```
 static uint8 startFrame[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    static uint8 colorFrame[32] = {1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1 , 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    static uint8 endFrame[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

and this:

```
static uint8 startFrame[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
static uint8 colorFrame[4] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
static uint8 endFrame[4]   = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff ,0xff};

SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(startFrame, 4);
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(colorFrame, 4);
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(endFrame,   4);
```

and this:

```
static uint8 startFrame[4] = {0,0,0,0};
static uint8 colorFrame[4] = {255, <R>, <G>, <B>};
static uint8 endFrame[4] = {255,255,255,255};

SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(startFrame, 4);
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(colorFrame, 4); // multiple of these for each LED
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(endFrame, 4);
```

If any of the above setups are correct then it must be an issue with how I'm writing to the SPI.

Comment: Your `static uint8 endFrame[32] = {1,1,1,1};` is neither a 32-element array of `1` bits (only the first 4 elements are 1, the others are 0), nor a 4-element array of `0xFF` bytes (32 bits). And you seem to only write one LED date [sic] field. Note that its "global" bitfield probably must not be `11111b` or the items could possibly be confused with the end frame marker when the pixel is white.

Comment: Why have you changed the question? Making corrections from comments and answers is not helpful. StackOverflow is not a running-update service.

Comment: If necessary add an addendum to the question. But how will anyone now reading the question make sense of the answers and comments?

Comment: @WeatherVane i understand. I've changed it back to the original questions + addendums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a couple problems here.

First of all... SPI is normally more or less transactional.  Unlike UART (as a common counter example) you don't just write whatever you want whenever you want.  You normally need to toggle a chip select (sometimes "slave select"), "clock out" words one at a time, then toggle the chip select the other way.  Without documentation on `SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray()`, its hard to say whether or not you can call it multiple times in the same transfer (between chip select toggling).

**EDIT:**  Never mind on the chip select thing.  This LED driver does not appear to have a chip select/enable line.  Just note for future reference this is unusual for SPI.

Second problem - I would assume `SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray()` puts out BYTES at a time, not bits.  Again, you did not provide documentation of the function so its hard to say.  If my assumption is correct, you would want `startFrame` to be `static uint8 startFrame[4] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};` as there are 8 bits in a byte giving you a 32-bit start-of-frame.  Same idea applies to color & end of frame.

Third problem - If I'm wrong about how the SPI function works, you're not fully initializing those arrays.  You declare arrays of 32 *bytes* and then only initialize 4 of those.

Comment: I very much appreciate your response. I've updated my question with the documentation for the put array method.

Comment: Would I not want my `endFrame` to be` {0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff};` since it has to be all 1's? Any my `startFrame` be `{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}` ??

Comment: Yes, you're correct on the start frame.  Sorry, got that backwards.  Also, FYI, from a quick glance, the "global" value sets an overall "brightness" via drive strength control where the R/G/B sets PWM duty cycle.  Don't be surprised if 1) altering the brightness *also* shifts the color, and 2) this device doesn't perfectly map to your expectations of RGB values for setting color.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare startFrame a 4 element array of uint8, not 32 element of uint8 which is 256 bits long, accordingly if the second argument of SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray is number of Bytes to write on SPI, you have to put 4 (4bytes - 32bit), not 32 (which is 256 bit)

```
static uint8 startFrame[4];
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(startFrame, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your array size to 4 instead of 32. uint8 already has 8 bits and 4 of those means 32 bits. Now unless you use some non-standard library, you need a bit of math to say what bits to set to 1 and which ones to set to 0. For instance, putting a 31 = 00001111b in one byte means you are setting the first 4 bits to 0 and the last 4 bits to 1. So, in your case, the code would be:

```
static uint8 startFrame[4] = {0,0,0,0};
static uint8 colorFrame[4] = {255, <R>, <G>, <B>};
static uint8 endFrame[4] = {255,255,255,255};

SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(startFrame, 4);
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(colorFrame, 4); // multiple of these for each LED
SPI_1_SpiUartPutArray(endFrame, 4);
```